# Orthogonal matching pursuit - am I using it wrong?

Tags: regression, least-squares, regularization, svd

I am trying out this method as a regularized regression, as an alternative to lasso and elastic net. I have 40k data points and 40 features. Lasso selects 5 features, and orthogonal matching pursuit selects only 1.

What could be causing this? Am I using omp the wrong way? Perhaps it is not meant to be used as a regression. Please let me know if you can thing of anything else I may be doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, using lasso and elastic net for regression is widely accepted. How do you use the OMP, what's the dictionary for maching ?

Comment: I use the original features(columns). Is this wrong? What should the dictionary be?